# UIWorkIntervalTiming workIntervalStart

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, xcode10.2

Getting console log while scrolling `ScrollView`. 
Is there way to remove this?

> 2019-03-27 12:33:34.109573+0530 MyApp[10465:46241] [UIWorkIntervalTiming] workIntervalStart: startTimestamp > targetTimestamp; rolling forward by 1.116667

Comment: This is also happening when scrolling UICollectionView.

Comment: Seeing the same thing while scrolling anything that inherits from (is a subclass of) UIScrollView, like UITableView or UICollectionView. I suspect it is Apple's internal diagnostic output used to analyze the scrolling performance. Haven't found any way to remove this.

Comment: There is no way to silence this output without silencing other, actual warnings. If you have been using Xcode for any length of time, you have seen these types of logs come and go. It used to be `BoringSSL SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN`. Next version of Xcode, it'll be something else.

Comment: This should be resolved with the latest versions: https://twitter.com/smileyborg/status/1128131061416771584

Answer (score 11):

I can observe the same issue with a `UICollectionView` and `UITableView`. I suspect it is a diagnostic output used to analyse the scrolling performance.

Note: I notice this issue from Xcode 10.2

in `UICollectionView` if you swapping too much faster than collection getting **Freeze** for few moment on **Simulator** but **Real Device** working fine.

> Earlier Xcode version this features is UIWorkIntervalTiming had its
>   logging privileges revoked

Answer (score 0):

Check any third party UI/animation related library used with in scroll view/table view cell.Issue might be with those libraries.

Answer (score -9):

You can simply silence the noise from the simulator:

1. Xcode Menu: *Product* -> *Scheme* -> *Edit Scheme*
2. Select the *Run(Debug)*
3. On Environment Variables section set **OS_ACTIVITY_MODE** = **disable**

   - Image

[image: Here is an image]

Unfortunately, I can't find any information relating to this issue in Apple documentation, but I believe that it is some diagnostic output which is used to analyze the scrolling performance.

Comment: This approach of silencing warnings is like throwing the baby out with the bathwater. It silences all the important debug logs. Across various Q&A on this site, this approach is recommended, but another solution is warranted.

Comment: @Alex Bes Could you tell what this warning means and why it's coming?

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale, unfortunately, I can't find any information relating to this issue in Apple documentation, but I believe that it is some diagnostic output which is used to analyze the scrolling performance.

Comment: Scrolling was terrible at the time of this warning, so silencing it is not a solution

Comment: This shouldn't be a solution.